# HTML form with two input fields

Tags: javascript, variables

i need your help. I have a `HTML` form with 2 `input` fields which uses java script function from the variables `var1` and `var2` to make variable `var3`. This variable `var3` is returned.
In IE it works, but only in Compatibility View. Does anyone have an idea?
Here is the code used:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function sucheingabe() {    
var val1 = document.getElementById("searchword-1").value;
var val2 = document.getElementById("searchword-2").value;
var val3 = (val1) + ('+') + (val2)
// alert (val3);
document.getElementById('searchword').value = val3;
}
</script>

<form class="search" action="index.php" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"     method="post">
<table style="width: 80%;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bordercolor="#111111">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td width="5%"> </td>
<td width="15%">
<div id="searchWhat">
<p class="topHeaders"><strong>Was</strong> <span style="font-size: xx-small;">(Jobtitel oder Firmenname)</span></p>
<input id="searchword-1" class="inputbox" alt="&gt;" maxlength="45" name="searchword-1" size="40" type="text" /></div>
</td>
<td width="5%"> </td>
<td width="15%">
<div id="searchWhere">
<p class="topHeaders"><strong>Wo</strong> <span style="font-size: xx-small;">(Ort oder Postleitzahl)</span></p>
<input id="searchword-2" class="inputbox" alt="&gt;" maxlength="45" name="searchword-2" size="40" type="text" /></div>
</td>
<td width="4%"><input onclick="sucheingabe();" name="Search" src="images/suchbutton.png" type="image" /> <input name="searchword" type="hidden" /> <input name="searchphrase" type="hidden" value="any" /> <input name="option" type="hidden" value="com_search" /> <input name="areas[0]" type="hidden" value="seminar" /></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try your javascript like below I hope this will work for you

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function sucheingabe() {    
var val1 = document.getElementById('<%= searchword-1.ClientID %>').value;
var val2 = document.getElementById('<%= searchword-2.ClientID %>').value;
var val3 = (val1) + ('+') + (val2)
// alert (val3);
document.getElementById('<%= searchword.ClientID %>').value = val3;
}
</script>
```

Comment: How did you get the idea the asker is using ASP.net?

Answer (score -1):

You have no element with id searchword.
You shoould do next:

```
<input name="searchword" id = "searchword" type="hidden" />
```

Comment: You have no element with id searchword... Yes thats it.. perfect. Thank you very much :-)